# WPF MVVM DataGrid does not populate anything from List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I created viewModel *CustomerViewModel* which looks like this.

```
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public CustomerViewModel() {
            customerList = null;
            _repository = new CustomersRepository();
        }

        public List<Customer> customerList;
        private CustomersRepository _repository;

        public void getAllCustomers() {
           customerList = _repository.GetCustomers();
        }
    }
```

And also I have a *CustomerView* which looks like

```
    public partial class CustomerView : UserControl
    {
       public CustomerView()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           var a = new ZzaDashboard.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel();
           a.getAllCustomers();
           this.DataContext = a;
       }
    }
```

And XAML of CustomerView for sure

```
   <UserControl x:Class="ZzaDashboard.Views.CustomerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"   
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZzaDashboard.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding customerList}"/>
</Grid>
```

And in MainWindow.xaml I just have this

```
 <Grid>
    <views:CustomerView x:Name="DataGrid"/>
</Grid>
```

Debug shows that in CustomerView.xaml.cs DataContext has a *customerList* which is not empty, but after running my program nothing shows on the mainWindow.

This is my first question, I am sorry for not being clear I guess, I will improve. Hope anyone will help.

Comment: `customerList` must be a property (`public List<Customer> customerList { get; set; }`)  not a field

Comment: How can I missed that. Thank you @ASh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is customerList need to a property not a field.
Thanks to [@ASh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506454/ash).